# LP Relaxation is unbounded

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, integer-programming, relaxations

How do I go about proving the integer linear program has an optimal solution, but that its linear program relaxation is unbounded? 
\begin{equation}
\begin{array}{cl}
{\max} & {x_1} \\
{\text{s.t.}} & {x_1 - \sqrt{5} x_2 = 0}
\end{array}
\end{equation}

I know that with the square root of 5 is irrational so I need to write down the LP relaxation and then prove how it is unbounded but I am confused how to go about that ..

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have not specified any integer variables.

Comment: Sorry x1 and x2 are both integers.

Comment: In addition to RobPratts answer, try graphing the set defined by the constraint $x_1 = \sqrt{5} x_2$.

Answer (score 1):

To show that the LP relaxation is unbounded, let an arbitrary $M$ be given and construct a feasible solution $(x_1,x_2)$ for which the objective $x_1\ge M$.  Explicitly, take $x_1=M$ and $x_2=M/\sqrt{5}$.

Comment: Are you able to break it down a bit more? Sorry I am still quite confused.